# How to update file in GIT using APIs - gives error 404 error

Tags: angular, git, github, httpclient, github-api

I am trying to update file in GIT using API and getting error code 404.

```
updateServersonGIT(servList: string): Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.http.put<Array<any>>("https://api.github.com/repos/amshreyas/servers/contents/serv.json",{"Authorization" : "token <my token>",servList}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I have generated oAuth token.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It may be failing because you haven't specified the required fields in the docs to go with the `PUT`: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-a-file

In particular you need to ensure that these fields are provided:

- `message` - the commit message to associate with the change
- `committer` - a JSON object containing the committer name and email
- `content` a base64-encoded string of the new file contents

Here's an example from the docs:

```
{
  "message": "my commit message",
  "committer": {
    "name": "Monalisa Octocat",
    "email": "octocat@github.com"
  },
  "content": "bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM="
}
```

It's not clear to me whether this is occurring, as the sample doesn't provide enough information to run locally for someone else.

It also might be failing if your token doesn't have `public_repo` set.

Comment: I did not put data and HttpOptions properly in http.put method. It is resolved now. Thanks!